# How to access tweet text in a json file to perform further analysis?

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I am using twitter API to fetch tweets about an input search term and storing them into a json file as shown in the code below. I am only interested in the tweet text and nothing else. How do I extract the text and ignore anything else? The end goal is to clean the individual tweets and perform sentiment analysis on them. Thanks!

```
    consumerKey = "xxx"
    consumerSecret = "xxx"
    accessToken = "xxx"
    accessTokenSecret = "xxx"

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
    auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    # Specify search term and count of tweets:
    searchTerm = input("Enter topic: ")
    limit = int(input("Enter the maximum number of tweets: "))

    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=searchTerm,count=limit, lang="en", tweet_mode='extended').items(limit)

    for tweet in tweets:

        # add to JSON                            
        with open('tweets.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
            json.dump(tweet._json, file)
```

Comment: try `json.dump(tweet._json['full_text'], file)`

Comment: also, open the file *before* iterating over `tweets`, so you'll save all tweet texts, otherwise you only save out the last tweet: `with open('tweets.json', 'wb') as file:
    for tweet in tweets:`...

Comment: Thanks @davedwards, that worked! It gave me the text but it only did so for a single tweet despite the limit being set to 5 tweets. 


`with open('tweets.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:

    for tweet in tweets:
        json.dump(tweet._json['text'], file)`

Comment: I think the `'w'` in `with open('tweets.json', 'w')`... may be deleting the file contents and only writing the current "tweet" text. maybe try with "append" `with open('tweets.json', 'a')`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading some stuff in the Twitter API documentation, I could see the JSON strucuture.

```
"tweet": {
"created_at": "Thu Apr 06 15:24:15 +0000 2017",
"id_str": "850006245121695744",
"text": "1\/ Today we\u2019re sharing our vision for the future of the Twitter API platform!\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/XweGngmxlP",
"user": {
  "id": 2244994945,
  "name": "Twitter Dev",
  "screen_name": "TwitterDev",
  "location": "Internet",
```

This is only a small piece of the JSON return, from a tweet.

As you know JSON text is a dictionary essentialy, therefore you can treat it like a normal dictionary.

Now to do this in python you need to know which key you want to get the value of. If I could give a recommendation it would be to use the requests module for your proyect, it is a lot simpler and more understandable.

```
for tweet in tweets:

    # add to JSON                            
    with open('tweets.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
        json.dump(tweets[tweet]["text"], file)
```

Instead of using json.dump you could use

```
for tweet in tweets:

    # add to JSON                            
    with open('tweets.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
        file.write(tweets[tweet]["text"])
```

By doing this we're calling the dictionary and giving it a certain key, in this case the variable tweet, then as you can see the dictionary tweets has anothe dictionary inside it that's why we call it again so we can get what we want in this case the value of the key "text"

Hope it helps!

Comment: when i do that, it throws the following error:

`TypeError: 'ItemIterator' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Could you post the twitter JSON response, and maybe your code to see

Comment: This is how my code looks like now:

`searchTerm = input("Enter topic: ")
limit = int(input("Enter the maximum number of tweets: "))
    
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm).items(limit)

with open('tweets.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:

    for tweet in tweets:
        json.dump(tweet._json['text'], file)`

It works but the json file contains only 1 tweet despite the limit being set to 5 tweets:

Comment: Output from json file:

Output (json file) :

`'"RT @krassenstein: BREAKING:  The NY Attorney General just received a federal court order blocking President Trump\u2019s delay of the fuel effic\u2026"'`

Comment: I meant the whole JSON response that you get when you request, some tweets